# Release invoice on new screen

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I need your help.
I have created a new screen, where I am calling all invoices pending release.

I have problems to release, I send a message where you request (you want to release).
It shows me the infinite message.
Only once should you ask me, then you should go out and follow the normal process.

[image: see attached image]

```
    public ProcessDocNew()
    {

        // Acuminator disable once PX1008 LongOperationDelegateSynchronousExecution [Justification]
        Document.SetProcessDelegate(
            delegate (List<ARInvoice> list)
            {
                List<ARRegister> newlist = new List<ARRegister>(list.Count);
                foreach (ARInvoice doc in list)
                {
                    newlist.Add(doc);
                }
                ProcessDoc(newlist, true);
            }
        );


        Document.SetProcessCaption(ActionsMensje.Process);
        Document.SetProcessAllCaption(ActionsMensje.ProcessAll);
    }

    public virtual void ProcessDoc(List<ARRegister> list, bool isMassProcess)
    {

        string title = "Test";
        string sms = "¿Stamp?";
        var Graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<ARInvoiceEntry>();
        ARInvoice document = Document.Current;
        PEFEStampDocument timbrar = new PEFEStampDocument();/*This is a class where it is, all my method*/

        if (isMassProcess == true)
        {
            Document.Ask(title, sms, MessageButtons.YesNo, MessageIcon.Question);
            {

                PXLongOperation.StartOperation(Graph, delegate
                {
                    timbrar.Stamp(document, Graph); /*here I have my release method*/
                });
            }
        }
    }

    public static class ActionsMensje
    {
        public const string Process = "Process";
        public const string ProcessAll = "Process All";
    }
```

I await your comments

Answer (score 0):

> Only once should you ask me, then you should go out and follow the
> normal process.

That is not how the processing pattern works. The process delegate is called for each record and is therefore not a valid location to display a message that should be shown only once.

You would need to add a custom action to achieve that behavior. The scenario you're looking for should be implemented with a processing filter checkbox and processing filter to comply with best practices:
[image]

Documentation on processing screens implementation is available here:

https://help-2019r2.acumatica.com/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=a007b57b-af69-4c0f-9fd1-f5d98351035f